# Incoming calls fail Asterisk

Tags: centos, sip, voip, asterisk, pbx

I have Asterisk 11.7.0 configured on CentOS 6.4 x64 with following `sip.conf` configuration:

```
[general]
register =>mynumber:mypass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
registertimeout=20
context=incoming
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=192.168.0.3
srvlookup=no
subscribecontext=from-sip

; The SIP provider
[VoIPProvider]
canreinvite=no
username=mynumber
fromuser=mynumber
secret=mypass
context=incoming
type=friend
fromdomain=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
nat=yes
insecure=very

; ext 100
[100]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=MyPass123
context=internal
mailbox=100@default
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no

; ext 200
[200]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=MyPass123
context=internal
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
```

And following `extensions.conf`:

```
[incoming]
; Ring on extension 100, 200 and the mobile phone.
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/100&SIP/200&SIP/VoIPProvider/*320423456789,150,r,t,)

; Pass unanswered call to a mobile phone
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/VoIPProvider/*320423456789,150,r)

; Still not answered? Pass unanswered calls to voicemail
exten => s,n,Voicemail(100,u)
exten => s,n,Hangup

[outgoing]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/VoIPProvider/${EXTEN})
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/VoIPProvider/${EXTEN})
exten => _XXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/VoIPProvider/${EXTEN})

[internal]
exten => _XXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})

; Calls to ext 100
exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/100,20)
exten => 100,n,VoiceMail(100,u)
exten => 100,n,Hangup

; Calls to ext 200
exten => 200,1,Dial(SIP/100,20)
exten => 200,n,Hangup
```

Whenever I dial my number from mobile phone I get a rejection signal. When I check the wireshark log i see three SIP packets:

MySipProvider -> Me:  INVITE sip:s@192.168.0.3:5060
Me -> MySipProvider:  401 Unauthorized
MySipProvider -> Me:  ACK sip:s@192.168.0.3:5060

and that's all there is. What could be happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Asterisk server is requesting authentication on the incoming call from your provider. My guess as to why is because the "host" value on your "VoIPProvider" entry in your sip.conf matches the IP address the call came from. You could check if this is the problem by temporarily commenting out the "host" value and seeing if the incoming call works. If so you will need to make adjustments to the "VoIPProvider" entry so it gets matched for outgoing calls only rather than incoming and outgoing (you used to do this by setting the "type" but I'm not up to date on the way it's done now).

Comment: I made so, and incoming calls now does not cause problems, now there is another problem:

-- Executing [XXXXXXXXX@outgoing:1] Dial("SIP/XXX-00000002", "SIP/VoIPProvider/XXXXXXXXX") in new stack

[Jan 4 08:17:48] WARNING[19884][C-00000003]: app_dial.c:2437 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)

== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/XXX-00000002' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'

localhost*CLI>    That means, when I call somewhere, command line writes this text and call ends... 

any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to solve outgoing problem you user context in internal and outgoing is not included in it please add the following line under context internal in extension.conf

[internal]
include = outgoing

so that your users can dial at SIP trunk.   :)

Answer (score 0):

use register string as this:
register => urusername:urpassword@IPaddress/providername

like in your case:

register => mynumber:mypassword@X.X.X.X/VoIPProvider

give it a go ithink this will solve the issue :)